# How do you make JQuery to load images on page load ?

Tags: jquery

The code below works fine with 'mousemove' but I want the images to display on page load, and nothing I have changed make the images display on page load.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Ian

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").mousemove(function () {

    $("li.fsn-level-1").each(function () {

      var imgCount = $(this).children("span").first().children("img").length;

      if (imgCount < 2) {
        $(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgPlus' src='images/plus.png' style='display:inline' />"); 
        $(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgMinus' src='images/minus.png' style='display:none' />");

      }

      var closed = $(this).hasClass("closed");
      var open = $(this).hasClass("open");
      var first = !closed && !open;
      if (first) {
        $(this).removeClass("open")
          $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("closed");
        var sub = $(this).children("ul");
        if (sub.length) {
          sub.hide();
        }

        var plus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgPlus']");
        if (plus.length)
          plus.show();

        var minus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgMinus']");
        if (minus.length)
          minus.hide();
      }


      $(this).unbind('hover').bind('hover', function () {
        CloseAllSubMenu();
        var closed = $(this).hasClass("closed");
        var open = $(this).hasClass("open");
        var first = !closed && !open;


        if (first || closed) {
          $(this).removeClass("closed");
          $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("open");
          var sub = $(this).children("ul");
          if (sub.length) {
            sub.show();
          }

          var plus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgPlus']");
          if (plus.length)
            plus.hide();

          var minus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgMinus']");
          if (minus.length)
            minus.show();

        }
        if (open) {

          $(this).removeClass("open")
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("closed");

          var plus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgPlus']");
          if (plus.length)
            plus.show();

          var minus = $(this).children("span").first().find("img[id='imgMinus']");
          if (minus.length)
            minus.hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see what you are trying to do exactly but this is what I found:

You are appending images after the page is ready here:

```
$(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgPlus' src='images/plus.png' style='display:inline' />");
$(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgMinus' src='images/minus.png' style='display:none' />");
```

This will cause the images to load at that point in time, ie: you are waiting for the page to be ready (loaded), then you are appending them, and forcing them to load after the page has loaded.

If you need to be dynamic (which it looks like), try running it before calling `$(document).ready();`. That way they will be included in the load for the document (and therefore anything that happens after that.

Comment: Do you mean move $(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgPlus' src='images/plus.png' style='display:inline' />");
$(this).children("span").first().prepend("<img id='imgMinus' src='images/minus.png' style='display:inline' />"); ABOVE the document.ready, if so, I tried that and it did not work. BTW you assumptions are correct. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just to ask a daft question, if you want to load the images on page_load, then why not just put the  tags on the page to start off with, so the images are already loaded as part of the document.

If you want to load the images when the document is ready (after page load) but not on mouse over then just remove this

```
$("body").mousemove(function () { }
```

...section from your javascript and the rest will fire straight away as it is no longer being wired up to the mousemove function.

Comment: I am using HTML5 with sections and articles and adding images at the page level does not work the same way as it does with earlier html versions! Thx.

Comment: Really? what is different about the <img> tag in HTML 5? I thought the only difference was a few unsupported attributes [W3C schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Comment: I had tried the <img tag> but could not got the image in the correct location. The image-background got the image in the correct location, but added too many images! I did find something interesting this morning, my development server is running vs2012 on windows server 2012 and has the issue, but my production server is running vs2012 on windows server 2008 r2 enterprise and does NOT have the issue, which is weird! I will contact Microsoft on this, thanks for your help !

Comment: After more research, I STILL have the issue :(

Comment: "The image-background added too many images" - do you mean that it was repeating? and if so you could try setting the background-repeat property to "repeat-y" so it only repeats vertically or "no-repeat" to not repeat at all?
Different development environments should not impact on the way the HTML is rendered, unless you have a different browser on each machine (sorry if I've completely got the wrong end of the stick here).